# Write to registry based on a condition

Tags: inno-setup

I want to write to registry based on OS. I have OS detection function in place and found out that you can put a check function in registry section, so tried following:

```
Root: HKLM; SubKey: Software\Microsoft\Windows; ValueType: dword; ValueName: Test; ValueData: 1; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist; Check: IsWindows7
```

But it didn't work, means that when I installed on Win7 and WinXP, it wrote the value to the  registry in both cases.

Here is the code to detect OS:

```
function IsWindows7(): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  // Windows 7 version is 6.1 (workstation)
  if (Version.Major = 6)  and
     (Version.Minor = 1) and
     (Version.ProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
  then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Try showing us the code for your `IsWindows7` check function. Why not just use the standard `MinVersion` and `OnlyBelowVersion` parameters?

Comment: Thanks for reply! It's fine that I can use standard parameters, but still I need to test it somewhere and then write to registry based on the test. All I'm asking is, is the given line above correct?

Comment: Yes it is. The first comment is right, the problem should come from IsWindows7, so you should add this function to the question. By a pure hasard do you test the right major vesrion number for Win7 (6 and not 7) ?

Comment: Ok, I have added the code for IsWindows7.

Comment: The IsWindows7() is right. It seems that's it's a good question...Could *createvalueifdoesntexist* conflict with *Check* ?

Comment: I took your code and tried it and did not have any issues.  It did not write the registry value on a Windows XP machine.  One suggestion I have would be to add some Log code into the IsWindows7 function so that you can see what's happening.

Comment: The registry directives support the built int `MinVersion: 6.1 / OnlyBelowVersion:` paramaters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see below my solution for you:

```
[Registry]

Root: HKLM; SubKey: {code:IsWindows7}; ValueType: dword; ValueName: Test; ValueData: 1; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist; Check: IsWindows7

[Code]

function IsWindows7(S: String) : string;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin

 GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  // Windows 7 version is 6.1 (workstation)
  if (Version.Major = 6)  and
     (Version.Minor = 1) and
     (Version.ProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
  then
    Result := '<registry path for win 7>'
else
    Result := '<registry path for other win os >';

end;
```

Happy coding!